# mongoDB: find by embedded value

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have some problems with mongoDB, i looked for an answer but i couldn't find anything
that solves my problem....

```
db.coders.save( {
'name': 'John', 
'languages' : { 'php':'bad','java':'good','brainfuck':'very bad'} 
});

db.coders.save( {
'name': 'Sarah', 
'languages' : { 'php':'good','java':'bad','brainfuck':'very bad'} 
});

db.coders.save( {
'name': 'Tom', 
'languages' : { 'php':'very good','java':'good','brainfuck':'bad'} 
});
```

now i want to find any coder that knows any language 'very good'...how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could not find it because it is impossible. None of the search operators works on the schema you provided.

The easiest workaround is to change schema a little bit:

```
db.coders.save( {
'name': 'John', 
'languages' : [ { n: 'php', v: 'bad'},{n:'java', v: 'good'},{n : 'brainfuck', v: 'very bad'}] 
});
```

In such a case you can query the data using the following query:

```
db.coders.find({'languages.v' : 'good'})
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Salvador, that changing the schema is better.

But I found that you can search using the $where operator.

```
db.coders.find({ $where : function() { for(lang in this.languages) { if (this.languages[lang] == 'very good') { return true; }  } return false;  }});
```

It might be a bit slowly as pointed in the docs.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-JavascriptExpressionsand%7B%7B%24where%7D%7D