# Faster query by value

Tags: performance, mongodb

I want to query MongoDB to find, in the `results` top level document, how many nested documents of it have value `0`.

For instance, in this collection:

```
{name: "mary", results: {"foo" : 0, "bar" : 8}}
{name: "bob", results: {"baz" : 9, "qux" : 0}}
{name: "leia", results: {"foo" : 9, "norf" : 5}}
```

my query should return `2`, because two of the documents have `0` as a value of a nested document of `results`.

Here's my attempt

```
db.collection.find({$where : function() { 
    for (var key in this.results) {
          if (this.results[key] === 0) { return true;} } return false; } })
```

which works on the above dataset, but is too slow. My real data are 100k documents, each having 500 nested documents inside `results`, and the above query takes a few minutes. Is it possible to design this query in a faster way?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do it, other than the one you are doing.

You can only change the schema or use aggregations but I don't think that this is what you want.

There is a post about it you can check here:
[mongoDB: find by embedded value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318499/mongodb-find-by-embedded-value)